# How do I convert a Eb/No from a dB value to a linear value

Tags: noise, signal

So for example how would I convert an Eb/No value of 2dB into a linear value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a power value, the decibel value is given by \$10\log_{10}{\text{SNR}}\$. To obtain the SNR from the dB value, take the inverse of this formula: \$\text{SNR} = 10^{\text{SNR}_{dB}/10}\$. In your example, 2 dB SNR corresponds to an SNR of approximately 1.58.

Note that this gives SNR *power* ratio. If you want an amplitude ratio (assuming there's a square-law relationship, as with electronic signals in many cases), take the square root of the power SNR.

Comment: The value I have is an energy per bit to noise power spectral density ratio (Eb/No),r snr per bit. Would I use the power ratio or amplitude ratio?

Comment: @dilinex Energy ratios and power ratios take the same conversion. If you have a energy/bit ratio in dB, you can get an energy/bit ratio on a linear scale using the 10log10 formula, without taking the square root.

Comment: I think there's a factor of 10 missing from the expression for SNR.

Comment: @Chu Thanks; fixed